# Is there any way to use a MongoDB ObjectId as an optional argument in C# without overloading the function

Tags: c#, mongodb, optional-parameters, objectid

Normally you cannot usr an ObjectId as an optional argument in C# due to the fact that ObjectId is a struct with no "Design time constant" default value.

ObjectId.Empty is a property that executes code and default(ObjectId) is not allowed for the same reason.

Does anyone have a solution on how to create a working design time constant so that the following statement would work?  (This is not the real method but an example)

```
MyObject LoadOrCreate(ObjectId id = somedefaultvalue)
{}
```

If I try this with any ov the above examples it will not compile?

I can of cause use a separate overload of the method but I rather use optionals than overload.

As I noted in my comment to the first answer, nullable is an option but one I prefer to not use due to having to cast back to not nullable.

So I am still looking for some "better" solution ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it Nullable and default to null?

Comment: Thought about that but I do not like nullables that are not so by default, You always end up having to cast them back and forth, but yes it's one solution.

Comment: It's not really a cast, it's more of a conversion (call to the static `explicit` operator which just calls `.Value`). This seems reasonable to me...

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
public static void SomeMethod(ObjectId id = default(ObjectId))
{
    // do something
}
```